# how to download file from webserver when url contains only file ID

Tags: c#, silverlight, iis, download, webserver

We have video clip storage and we want to provide url link to the end user for the clips so that end user can start downloading the clips by clicking on the url. But trick here is url link is not direct path to the clip file stored on the virtual folder but url contains clip ID. It might look like,

```
           www.xyz.com/clipstore/ID
```

When end user click on the url, server should search for the clip in the clip storage,  process the clip ( convert from one format to other format) and start download at end user location.
    Can anyone please guide us how server can initiate download for the end user when url is not directly pointing to the file but ID of it. 
    We are using IIS 6 / 7 , C# on the server side. Client is silverlight based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and quite straight forward in ASP.net MVC.
For the sake of example, I have hard coded the mime type to "image/png", but i should be according to file type.

```
 public ActionResult clipstore(string id)
    {
        var path = GetFilePathByID(id);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);

        var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);            

        FileContentResult file = File(fileBytes, "image/png");

        return file;
    }
```